# OSX Window server vulnerabilities on catalina

Tags: security, x11, xquartz

This question will be a long one, as I have given lot of time in doing research and also I have attached all my research in the question itself.

The [window server/ display server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_server) used on linux is `X11`, on which OSX's window server `XQuartz` (now almost deprecated) was based on. Recently it was discovered in 2013 that this `X11` has a very big vulnerability. [article here](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/a-lesser-known-reason-to-migrate-from-x-org/).

The above article mentions the following

> For those that don't know, X was originally designed and released in
> 1985 and X11 in 1987. X.org replaced X11 and was originally released
> April 6, 2004. When X was originally conceived, the computing world
> was in a completely different state. Both X and X.org lack a few very
> important security features that are critical for modern era usage and
> hardware:
>
> 1. All X applications have access to everything on your screen
> 2. All X applications can register to receive every keystroke, regardless of which window said keystrokes are typed within
> 3. Applications such as browsers can be remotely controlled such that keystrokes can be forged as if the user were typing them
> 4. The xhost + option can completely disable any security on the display

Older `XQuartz` (used by apple) was very much based on this `X11`, and hence these vulnerabilities were also there on MacOS.

[XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org/) official website mentions the following

> The XQuartz project is an open-source effort to develop a version of
> the X.Org X Window System that runs on OS X. Together with supporting
> libraries and applications, it forms the X11.app that Apple shipped
> with OS X versions 10.5 through 10.7.

In 2017, apple made a shift away from this `XQuartz` as the main display server/ window server as mentioned [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201341).

> About X11 for Mac
>
> X11 is no longer included with Mac, but X11 server and client
> libraries are available from the XQuartz project.
>
> Apple created the XQuartz project as a community effort to further
> develop and support X11 on Mac. The XQuartz project was originally
> based on the version of X11 included in Mac OS X v10.5. There have
> since been multiple releases of XQuartz with fixes, support for new
> features, and additional refinements to the X11 experience. Apple is a
> contributor to the XQuartz project and has worked to ensure that X11
> works as expected with macOS and latest available versions of XQuartz.
>
> X11 server and client libraries for macOS are available from the
> XQuartz project at [www.xquartz.org](http://www.xquartz.org). Download the latest version
> available.

Currently apple uses the following mentioned in [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/246156/380238) answer from 2016 (almost 4 years old) which is also valid today as mentioned [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics) on apple's website.

My question now; Is this [mentioned technology](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/246156/380238), currently used by apple still as vulnerable as the `X11` on major linux distros? Is the `freely accessing other running apps' data and keystrokes` vulnerability still there today or has it been solved?

Comment: I am confused. X11 is not the normal macos gui very few people will have it. What are you asking. All x11 servers on osx have been open source and I don't think have much input from Apple

Comment: @user151019 sorry, I did some mistake in my research. So by any means, is macos Quartz vulnerable like the XQuartz or X11?

Comment: The way I heard it Apple's display engine was based on the NeXTStep implementation of Display Postscript and had nothing, or little, to do with X11.

Answer (score 3):

Apple does not use X11 or XQuartz in any way. It's an entirely third-party app, created to run the **X** windows environment inside Apple's own **Quartz** graphics system.

The last build of XQuartz was released in 2016. Most people only use it to run particular software, like FontForge. They are unlikely to use it as a general computing environment.

I suspect that the security problems you mention only exist within the X environment, rather than bleeding out into MacOS's own window server. Apple has introduced all sorts of security features to restrict applications' operations and scope of influence, so I would be very surprised if these flaws existed.